# Update an specific value inside the state with the reducer

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, redux

I'm trying to update an specific value **(in this case a comment inside a list)** inside an array of objects that is inside the state. In this case the comment inside the **msgs** key.

```
 const list = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "list text",
    msgs: [{
      id: 1,
      comment: "comment",
      commentID: "ab37afa-c17-e4f-f103-4715b72f14ec"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "list text 2",
    msgs: [{
      id: 2,
      comment: "comment2", <--- trying to update this value
      commentID: "ab37afa-c17-e4f-f103-4715b72f14ec-2"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      comment: "comment3",
      commentID: "ab37afa-c11323127-e4f-f103-4715b72f14ec-2"
    }]
  }
];
```

**I'm currently trying this with the reducer:**

```
case "EDIT_COMMENT":
      temp = state.filter((list => list.id === parseInt(action.comment.id)))  //getting the list that I want
      const msgs = [].concat(...temp).map(x=> ({
        id: x.id,
        comment : x.comment,
        commentID : x.commentID
        })) // trying to get the messages inside the state


     // I honestly don't know what to put here
      return msgs.map( msg => {
        if(msg.commentID === action.payload.commentID){
          return {...}
        }
      }        
        )
```

I cannot get the answer/solution to update the data that I want with the reducer, if someone can help me with the problem, i'd appreciate it.
Thanks in advance, have a nice weekend:)

Comment: Why aren't your ids unique?

Comment: @larz I created the key id inside the msgs because I didn't know how to reach to it, I don't know if it's necessary tho for what i'm trying to do right now. every comment has its own commentID which is unique. 
It is bad to set the structure like that??. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting to update any nested `msg` comment, on any given item of `state` (which I assume matches the form of the list shown in your question) - in which case, a simple solution might be as follows:

```
case "EDIT_COMMENT": {

  return state.map(messageItem => {

    return {
      // Clone input messageItem
      ...messageItem,

      // Overwrite msgs field with new msgs array
      msgs : messageItem.msgs.map(commentItem => {

        if(commentItem.commentID === action.payload.commentID) {
          return {
            // Clone input commentItem
            ...commentItem,

            // Overwrite fields that this action should update,
            // on commentItem matching by comment id ie, "comment"
            // from action payload
            comment : action.payload.comment
          }      
        }
        else {
          // If message does not match actions comment id, return
          // a clone of commentItem to mapped list
          return {...commentItem}
        }
      })
    }    
  });
}
```

The assumptions here are that;

- `state` is an array matching the form of `list` as shown in your question
- the `commentId` in your action payload is unique to a comment in the `msg` sub-array.
- the `comment` field in your action payload comtains the new comment string to update an existing matched comment

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You want to map through everything, return it as is unless it matches `action.payload.commentID`.  If it does match, return THAT as is, except update the comment.

```js
const list = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "list text",
    msgs: [{
      id: 1,
      comment: "comment",
      commentID: "ab37afa-c17-e4f-f103-4715b72f14ec"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "list text 2",
    msgs: [{
      id: 2,
      comment: "comment2", // <--- trying to update this value
      commentID: "ab37afa-c17-e4f-f103-4715b72f14ec-2"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      comment: "comment3",
      commentID: "ab37afa-c11323127-e4f-f103-4715b72f14ec-2"
    }]
  }
];

const action = {
  payload: {
    commentID: 'ab37afa-c17-e4f-f103-4715b72f14ec-2',
    comment: 'Updated Comment',
  }
}

console.log(list.map(listItem => {
  return {
    ...listItem,
    msgs: listItem.msgs.map(msg => {
      if (msg.commentID === action.payload.commentID) {
        return {
          ...msg,
          comment: action.payload.comment
        }
      }
      return msg;
    })
  }
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?
(I just made up the structure of the action)

```
case "EDIT_COMMENT":
    return state.map((list) => {
        if (list.id === parseInt(action.listId) {
            list.msgs = list.msgs.map((msg) => {
                if (msg.id === action.commentId) {
                    msg.comment = action.comment;
                }
                return msg;
            }
        }
        return list;
    });
    break;
```